# The Kafka Consumer cannot find any available Kafka brokers to connect to

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

The Kafka Consumer cannot find any available Kafka brokers to connect to.
I was hoping to be able to observe the logs, because when I use docker-compose up -d, the topics created after starting kafka and zookeeper are exiting
The error follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/servico_pagamento.py", line 22, in <module>
     enviar_pagamento()
   File "/app/servico_pagamento.py", line 5, in enviar_pagamento
     producer = KafkaProducer(
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 381, in __init__
     client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, metric_group_prefix='producer',
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 244, in __init__
     self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 900, in check_version
     raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
 kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

If you need the .yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - kafka-network
    
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - kafka-network

  pagamento:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.pagamento
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    networks:
      - kafka-network
networks:
  kafka-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is the .py related code

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json

def enviar_pagamento():
    producer = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092',
        api_version=(0,11,5),
        value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8')
    )
    pagamento = {
        'id_pedido': 123,
        'valor': 50.0,
        'status': 'pendente'
    }

    producer.send('pagamentos_email', value=pagamento)
    producer.send('pagamentos_notificacao', value=pagamento)
    producer.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    enviar_pagamento()
```

Comment: Show us the `servico_pagamento.py` file.

Comment: Please include that in the question.  The question itself should have all of the necessary details.  Plus it's hard to read code in a comment.

Comment: I performed the update

Answer (score 0):

1. Kafka container doesn't start immediately. Make sure it actually starts; the Bitnami container does not need Zookeeper, so wherever you've copied from is out of date, and you will need different environment variables
2. Your Python code cannot connect to a server that isn't running or healthy by the time it starts up. You have to wait or manually retry the connection in a loop

> the topics created after starting kafka and zookeeper are exiting

It's not possible to create topics if Kafka is exiting. As mentioned, Zookeeper isn't being used

> was hoping to be able to observe the logs

Remove `-d`

Comment: Add the time interval and got the same error: windows-pagamento-1 exited with code 0

Comment: Added where? As mentioned, Kafka may be failing to actually start. Python code changes wont fix this